# Use of "when it comes to" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: expressions, idioms

As I talk to someone about some subjects,
could I use "when it comes to" at the beginning of sentence?

For example:

> When it comes to food, I like...

Also, is it normally used in casual conversation?

Comment: 'When it comes to X,', like 'Regarding X, 'Speaking about X' etc, is a parenthetical. It can be used as a sentence-introducer, when an independent clause (the matrix sentence) must follow. These examples are pragmatic markers subclass focusing devices / domain specifiers (perhaps redirectional). They are commonly used, especially in conversation.

Comment: I would use "when it comes to x" at the beginning of a sentence when speaking, but I probably would not use "Regarding x" in speech, unless it was a very formal situation. pragmatic markers subclass focusing devices? Is that correctly stated?

Comment: It's perfectly natural in informal speech. The clause is a domain adjunct since it restricts the domain to which the rest of the clause applies. Such adjuncts are characteristically prosodically detached, with the status of supplements. Cf. also "As regards food, I only eat vegetarian".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it.  It's an sort of "build up" to talking about a subject. It has a similar meaning to "Regarding..." and it's probably most commonly seen written, at the beginning of an article for example:

*"When it comes to computers, most of us know how to use them but don't know how they work..."*

It's like a signal to the reader to say "This article is about computers.".

In conversation it's most commonly used as a way of responding to what someone else has said, as a way of saying "I also have something to say on that subject", eg

> Person A:"I love that new stone-fired pizza place on Market Street."
>
> Person B:"When it comes to pizza, you have to go stone-fired every time."